# how to post array from controller side and add in to table using angularjs mvc c#?

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework

hi i am create small demo for products crud operation.i have the 2 table Products and ProductItems. i want to submit time add 1st product table entry and after this productid get and add into ProductItems but how can do that using entity framework.and i am also pass the ProductItems array using http post method but i m not get server side always getting 0 count.so can you please know how can do that this stuff.here i am show my entity,method below listed.

this is my Product Entity :

```
[Table("Products")]
public class Products
{
    [Key]
    public int pid { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public string description { get; set; }

    public string image_url {get;set;}
}
```

this is my ProductItems entity :

```
    [Table("ProductItems ")]
    public class ProductItems 
   {
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Products")]
    public int pid {get; set;}

    public int Qty { get; set; }

    public Decimal Rate { get; set; }

    public virtual Products Products { get; set; }
}
```

this is my controller.js :

```
$scope.AddProduct = function () {
        var P =
            {                    
                name : $scope.ProductName,
                description : $scope.description,
                ProIList: $scope.ProItemslist,
                image_url : $scope.Image
            };        

                var GetData = PService.AddPro(P.image_url, P);
                GetData.then(function (msg) {

                }, function (err) {
                });

        }
    }
```

this is my service.js

```
this.AddPro = function (file, P) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("name", P.name);
    formData.append("description", P.description);
    formData.append("ProIList", P.ProIList);  // this is array list      

    var Response = $http.post("/Product/AddProduct", formData,
        {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        })
    .success(function (res) {
        Response = res;
    })
    .error(function () {
    });
    return Response;
}
```

this is my controller Method:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("AddProduct")]
    public string AddProduct(string name, string description, IList<ProductItems> ProIList) // here i m not getting array 
    {
        Products objP = new Products();            
        string Res = "";

                    objP.name = name;
                    objP.description = description;                       
                    db.Promotions.Add(objP); // and here add product is done now want to add ProductItems table entry so how can do 
                   db.SaveChanges();                  
        return Res;
    }
```

so here i am clear all listing method class now any one know how can do that this stuff then please let me know.

Comment: any one know how can post array from server side??

Answer (score 0):

what i usually do to post is create an object then that is what i will pass in my $http.post. also make sure that the object structure that you will post has the same structure on you ProductItems.

In your case, you should have a view model so you will not have a problem when you post

example:

```
public class ProductsViewModel{
   public string name {get;set;}
   public string description {get;set;}
   public List<ProductItems> productList{get;set;}
}
```

api post call

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddProduct")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAssessment(List<ProductsViewModel> model)
{
}
```

your angularjs code should look like

```
var products=[
  {
    name: "Product 1"
    description: "prod description"
    productList: [
        {
          //put data of product list here
        }
     ]
}
];
var Response = $http.post("/Product/AddProduct", products,
    {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
.success(function (res) {
})
.error(function () {
});
```

hope this helps

upate:
this if for image upload api

```
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
                 throw new 
                HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
         //do your upload functions here


         } catch(Exception e){

         }
     }
```

in angularjs,

use ngFileUpload

```
 Upload.upload({
                    url: apiUrl + '/File',
                    data: { file: file },
                }).then(function (response) {
                    //the api should return the url of your image.
                     //you can now use the code above. add it to the object 
                    //then post it to addproducts
                });
```

Comment: actually my productItems div is in ng-repeat and there one button click on button automatically div is append so i am submit form i m get array of ProductItems and i m also post image also with so i want to used form with append data so using form data append any idea?

Comment: with your solution how can submit image?

Comment: I edited it to accept array of products. you can use array.push() if you want to append your products in angularjs

Comment: i use a different post when i upload an image. check this the ngFileUpload https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload directive for image upload

Comment: with my que it's not possible??

Comment: it is possible, try uploading the image then on success promise, post the product items with the image url

Comment: can you please edited your solution with your last comment

Comment: and with my code i m getting all filed on api side like name,description,also image but just not getting list so can you please know where is my mistek

Comment: hi Redan can you please help me for that

Comment: kindly check my update. try it and feel free to modify my code to suit your needs. thanks

Comment: hi @Redan thanks for the helping but with my code i m fix it issue i m getting this list on api side requset.form("Key") using get. and yes your solution it's also correct np.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a perfect place to use `ViewModel`.

I am assuming the format of data you want to pass to `Server` has One `Name` field, One `Description` field and One `List` of Product.

and this is how you are going to represent on `Client` Side (and not the was you have done)

```
var products= {
   name: "Product 1",
   description: "prod description",
   productList: [
    {
      //put data of product list here
    }
   ]
};
```

and the form the VM `ViewModel`

```
var clientSideVM = {
  Name: products.name,
  Description: products.description,
  Products: products.productList
};
```

post it to the `Server`

```
$http.post("AddProduct", clientSideVM)
   .then(function(response) { 
       // Access The Response Object
   }, function(error) {
       // Access The Error Object 
   });

//Server Side Code
//Exactly matching VM
public class CustomViewModel {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public List<ProductItems> Products { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost, Route("AddProduct")]
public string AddProduct(CustomViewModel viewModel) {
  //here you have all you data from Client Side,
  var name = viewModel.Name;
  // Work on them here
  //Rest of your Code
}
```